# GIMP Soft brush isn't soft

Tags: gimp, brush

This has been annoying me for a while, essentially, my basic brush options now only have one option: [image]

I believe it might be something to do with colour options, as that doesn't work either. I can still edit essentially everything about the brush and I can even change the brush to one of the weirder presets.

Unless I'm dumb(likely) I haven't seen anyone else with this problem. If anyone has the solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

(I tried it again without my plug-ins and the problem is still there)

Comment: What about the hardness slider (= the one between Spacing and Force) in the tool options dialog? See this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FWdk.png In the left the hardness slider was 100%, in the middle it was 50% and in the right (=shown value) it's 0%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardness setting is at 100% in the tool options which will make the brush a hard brush.  It should be set to 25% for the "*2. Hardness 025*" brush.  Press the reset button [image] beside the Hardness to revert to 25% - i.e. the native hardness of the brush, or you can move the slider manually.

[image]